# Reading a setting in IsolatedStorage from another page

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-7

Simple question, asked before but no one gave me the right answer so I'm going to be very specific.

I need to read two settings form `IsolatedStorage` in Windows Phone. The settings are `ExitAlert` and `OrientationLock`. I have already set up the settings, they save just fine, I just need to know how to read them from another page. The page the variables are set on is `Settings.cs`, and I need to read the settings from `MainPage.xaml.cs`. I also need to know how to only do something if the variable is true or false. I think I'm supposed to use an if-then-else statement, but I just want to double check.

My app is written in C#. This is the code that I'm using to store the settings:

```
using System;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Google_
{
    public class AppSettings
    {

        IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStore;

        // isolated storage key names
        const string ExitWarningKeyName = "ExitWarning";
        const string OrientationLockKeyName = "OrientationLock";

        // default values
        const bool ExitWarningDefault = true;
        const bool OrientationLockDefault = false;

        public AppSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the settings for this application.
                isolatedStore = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception while using IsolatedStorageSettings: " + e.ToString());
            }
        }


        public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
        {
            bool valueChanged = false;

            // If the key exists
            if (isolatedStore.Contains(Key))
            {
                // If the value has changed
                if (isolatedStore[Key] != value)
                {
                    // Store the new value
                    isolatedStore[Key] = value;
                    valueChanged = true;
                }
            }
            // Otherwise create the key.
            else
            {
                isolatedStore.Add(Key, value);
                valueChanged = true;
            }

            return valueChanged;
        }

        public valueType GetValueOrDefault<valueType>(string Key, valueType defaultValue)
        {
            valueType value;

            // If the key exists, retrieve the value.
            if (isolatedStore.Contains(Key))
            {
                value = (valueType)isolatedStore[Key];
            }
            // Otherwise, use the default value.
            else
            {
                value = defaultValue;
            }

            return value;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            isolatedStore.Save();
        }

        public bool ExitWarning
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(ExitWarningKeyName, ExitWarningDefault);
            }
            set
            {
                AddOrUpdateValue(ExitWarningKeyName, value);
                Save();
            }
        }

        public bool OrientationLock
        {
            get
            {
                return GetValueOrDefault<bool>(ExitWarningKeyName, OrientationLockDefault);
            }
            set
            {
                AddOrUpdateValue(OrientationLockKeyName, value);
                Save();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If anything is unclear, just let me know so I can explain further. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is add the following to my AppSettings class:

```
private static AppSettings _default = new AppSettings();
/// <summary>
/// Gets the default instance of the settings
/// </summary>
public static AppSettings Default
{
    get
    {
        return _default; 
    }
}
```

Then you can just use AppSettings.Default from anywhere in your project:

```
if (AppSettings.Default.ExitWarning)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this works. Would I just use something like `if (AppSettings.ExitAlert == true)` to get a specific boolean value...?

Comment: So that should work from any page? EDIT: Ahh! It works perfectly! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[]` for storing application-wide settings. They can be accessed from any page and you don't need isolated storage to store them.

Example:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["ExitWarning"] = true;
```